# The removal of bails or lightning of stumps(run out)

Tags: rules, cricket

Run outs depends on the removal of bails or lightning of stumps(LED stumps) on which action does the run out depends? in matches where LED stumps are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LED Wickets are not part of the [Laws of the Game](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/), so you would need to refer to the specific playing conditions for whichever tournament you're interested in. For simplicitly, we can look at the [September 2018 Men's T20I Playing Conditions](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2018/09/27/982bcd9d-4b22-43c9-b67b-9837c6898ecb/05-Mens-T20I-Playing-Conditions-2018.pdf):

> Where LED Wickets are used [...] the moment at which the wicket has been put down [...] shall be deemed to be the first frame in which the LED lights are
>   illuminated and subsequent frames show the bail permanently removed
>   from the top of the stumps.